Sonarcloud is ignoring jacoco aggregate coverage results
I have a complex java project with many maven modules. Some of these modules are covered by unit tests. Coverage results from this tests are propagated to sonarcloud instance.
I also have special module for integration tests, where are performed more complex tests.
Next to this modules is another special module just for jacoco coverage aggregation.
My goal is to increase coverage by including results from integration tests module, but for some reason these tests are completely ignored.
The structure of the project is something like this:
parent
|- child1
|- child2
|- integration-tests
|- coverage-aggregation

Jacoco configuration for coverage-aggretagion module is following:
<!-- org.jacoco.jacoco-maven-plugin -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>

        <!-- Merge results from all coverage reports into single one -->
        <execution>
            <id>merge-results</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>merge</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <fileSets>
                    <fileSet>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/../../</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/target/coverage-reports/jacoco.all.exec</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileSet>
                </fileSets>
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/aggregate.exec</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <!-- Generate merged report from all modules -->
        <execution>
            <id>create-mega-merged-report</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>XML</format>
                </formats>
                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/aggregate.exec</dataFile>
                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-mega-aggregate</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>report-aggregate</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
            </goals>

            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>XML</format>
                </formats>
                <includeCurrentProject>true</includeCurrentProject>
                <dataFileIncludes>
                    <dataFileInclude>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/aggregate.exec</dataFileInclude>
                </dataFileIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

    </executions>
</plugin>

Does anyone had same issue or know how to force sonarcloud to not ignore results from aggregated results?
Thank you.
I'm aware of similar question Jacoco report-aggregate - Include report of aggregate project, but it did not help me.

Have you solved it in the meantime?

I have not solved it yet, but I have a discussion about this issue on the sonar community forum https://community.sonarsource.com/t/ignored-coverage/124812?u=stechy1
